# Changing WSO2 IS Certificate Leads to Login Failures

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, keystore, wso2-identity-server

I have been trying to trouble shoot this for several days now and I am coming up with nothing.  I need WSO2 IS to use our company's certificate and key but every time I make the change I am unable to login our web application.  Logging into IS via the admin panel seems to not be hindered.

When I login to our web app I get the following error in the browser:

```
Error when processing the authentication request!
```

Here is a portion of the wso2carbon.log file regarding the login attempt.

http://pastebin.com/FrtVUWiU

It appears the ldap authentication is successful and then I think it fails to complete the SAML process.

If I use the default keystore it works fine but I have to confirm the security exception from the untrusted CA.

I followed the instructions from the wso2 documentation; creating a new keystore with the key, cert, and intermediate CA certs then adding the public key to the client-truststore.jks.  I also tried to import the cert and key into the existing keystore, making sure to delete the wso2carbon key before making an attempt.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Creating+a+New+Keystore

I have tried to make sure the intermediate CA certs are installed in the Java cacerts on both the IS host and our host serving the web app.  So I think I have all of the bases covered for some untrusted error.  Not sure what I could be missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that this is not an issue with trusted certificate. But in your keystore,  there must be a private key entry. This alias name of this private key entry,  must be equal with the `<Security><KeyStore><KeyAlias>` configuration of the  `carbon.xml` file.  If it is not,  above error can be generated. So,  please try to double check it.

According to the code, resident IDP data is loaded using [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/idp-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/idp/mgt/IdentityProviderManager.java) code.  So,  we analyze, only place that is related to certificate loading is line `165` (As you are truing with super tenant).  So, it has following code

`cert = keyStoreManager.getDefaultPrimaryCertificate();`

This can be go wrong,  if there is some issue with keystore configuration in the `carbon.xml` file.

Comment: I know this was answered some time ago but you were 100% correct.  The aliases didn't match up between both of the keystores.  Thank you for your help!